# kABPersonLastName not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook, abperson

I use this code, for `kABPersonEmailProperty` it works, but for `kABPersonLastNameProperty` not.
Why?

```
NSMutableArray *allNumbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:CFArrayGetCount(people)];
for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(people); i++) {
    ABRecordRef person2 = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(people, i);
    ABMultiValueRef numbers = ABRecordCopyValue(person2, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    for (CFIndex j=0; j < ABMultiValueGetCount(numbers); j++) {
        NSString* number = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(numbers, j));
        [allNumbers addObject:number];
    }
    CFRelease(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A contact only has one last name. Simply do:

```
NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person2, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
```